# Should “to do ” be before what or after what?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> What did you come here to do?
>
> To do What did you come here ?

Is there any difference between two sentence in meaning?

Answer (score -1):

The first example is idiomatic and grammatical. The second is not. There are times when 'what' will follow 'to do', for example, "I want you to do what I asked."